# Matlab -- Finding missing number in a list

Tags: matlab

I have a relatively large data set, and I'm looking for the missing number via MatLab.

For example, I have a list of numbers that might look like:

`1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, 10.....`

You can see the 8 is missing here.  The list is in the thousands, and there are maybe just a couple missing numbers.  How can I find out which ones are missing?  My search only turned up useful results without randomly repeating numbers.  Seems simple but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
% Your data:
data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, 10];

for i = 1:data(end)
    if (isempty(find(data==i)))
        disp(['i = ',num2str(i)]);
    end
end
```

Which will print out the values of the missing elements.

---

Or even simpler you could just use the ismember() function to construct
the set difference in just a single line below.

```
% First enter your data and construct 'set':
data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10, 10];
set = data(1):data(end);
```

Then to determine which elements of 'set' are also in 'data':

```
ismember(set, data)
```

The output then shows the locations in 'set' where the data is missing:

```
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it was sufficient for what I needed.  Much appreciated!!  And thanks to everyone else for the other variations I may try and add to my code.

Comment: @User, ok great, I added an even simpler version as a 2nd option in case that is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Use `unique`, like this:

```
B=unique(A);     % A is your data
C=setdiff(1:max(A),B)
```

and `C` is your desired missing numbers.

**EDIT** (afetr seeing claj's answer):

If your data starts from another value (not "1"), the second line should be:

```
C=setdiff(min(A):max(A),B)
```

**EDIT2:** (according to Eitan's comment)

```
C=setdiff(min(A):max(A),A);
```

This line replaces the two lines from the original answer.

Comment: I think you can manage without unique`, *i.e*: `setdiff(1:max(A), A)`

Comment: @EitanT Yes, I think so also... didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ismember()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function to check if a number is member of the data array

```
% set your data array
maximum = max(data);
minimum = min(data);

for i= minimum:maximum

    if ~ismember(i,data);
        disp([num2str(i) , ' is missed']);
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [unique](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) list of values in the array.

Find the min and max numbers in this unique set (these should be the same numbers as in the array, but quicker to find).

Create a range from min to max like `[min:max]`.

Make a [set difference](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) of the uniqued array and the range-set.

This gives you the missing numbers in decently quick way.

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to a few of the above but the simplest i've found is

`find(~ismember(set,data))`

which will return the indices of the members of set that are not in data

Comment: I think `setdiff(set,data)` is easier, and returns the actual values missing, rather than their indices.